# Without AOC, every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable

Tags: analysis, logic, set-theory

My analysis prof constructed a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ today. A student noticed he used axiom of choice and asked for a construction that doesn't use it. Then, another student responded that there exist models of ZF where every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable--which blows my mind. Can anybody show me a proof of this? Also, ZF is just a set of axioms, what did my classmate mean by "models of ZF"?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/42220/158937

Comment: If you don't know what models are, I'd suggest learning some logic before diving into this question.

Comment: See the [Solovay Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model#:~:text=Solovay%20(1970)%20in%20which%20all,existence%20of%20an%20inaccessible%20cardinal.)  But I second the comment that you should first look up what models are.

Comment: Without $AC$ you can't construct a non-measurable set. But you can't prove that they don't exist, either. So your title is not quite right.

Comment: @Ian "ZF-C is equiconsistent with ZF-C+axiom of determinacy which does get you that" That's not true: $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ proves the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (this is nontrivial, but basically $\mathsf{ZF+AD}\vdash$ "$L_{\omega_1}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$"), and so has strictly greater consistency strength. (In fact it has **much** greater consistency strength.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the correction, been a while since I reviewed this topic.

Comment: Without Alexandra Ocasio-Cortez everything  is possible.